# Would somebody be able to create a list of map waypoints in Grand Theft Auto V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm totally blind, and have previously loved playing all of the games in the GTA series; whilst missions arn't playable, cheats make the game a much more interesting experience, and the First Person View in GTA V makes the game even more playable due to wider use of stereo positioning with audio output.

I realise that this is a big ask, but I was wondering if somebody would be able to put together a list of map waypoints for me (the map screen when you press start and then select the map option which is the first that immediately has focus in the pause menu). This would be for easier navigation when calling a taxi - rather than having to constantly select a waypoint, get in the taxi and then confirm - which gets my character to verbally announce the location that was previously selected, I could then know for a fact which waypoint was selected. I realise that several PoIs also have what I call sub-PoIS (where you can use the left/right cursors to also select a location within that location) - it'd be amazing if I could also have these, if at all possible.

Thank you - I realise that this is a big ask

Comment: The map waypoints list is not always the same. Things are added and removed from it as game play progresses.